# Install/Update .NET Core 1.0 on Ubuntu, which package version?

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core

Now that .NET Core 1.0 is released, I'd like to try it out on Ubuntu, but [the official install docs](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu) still reference Preview 2:

`sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003121`

Tab completion on the dotnet package name returns 215 results, with "major" versions appearing to be "beta", "preview1", "preview2", "preview3", and "rc2", each of which has numerous build numbers available.

[This Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) implies that "RC2" is the latest (which makes sense based on the usual definition of those terms) but it also has dozens of builds available, most but not all of which are numerically sortable.

So do I just install the latest build (`dotnet-dev-1.0.0-rc2-002678` as I write this) or is there some tracking meta-package available? Are the official docs really that far out of date? Or is `preview2-003121` somehow a "blessed" version on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow the guide you linked to at https://www.microsoft.com/net/core by installing `dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003121`. That guide should be always up to date.

The confusion is caused by the fact that .Net Core itself is at a version 1.0, but the tools to create, build and publish .Net Core applications and libraries (contained in the .Net Core SDK) are still in preview (specifically Preview 2). [From the .Net Core 1.0 announcement:](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/06/27/announcing-net-core-1-0/)

> There are two main distributions for .NET Core:
>
> - .NET Core – Includes the .NET Core runtime and framework. The current version is “.NET Core 1.0”
> - .NET Core SDK – Includes .NET Core and the .NET Core Tools. The current version is “.NET Core SDK 1.0 Preview 2”.
>
> The .NET Core Tools are considered “Preview” currently. We chose “Preview” because we are not yet done shaping the tools. We know that there are still some changes coming.

The ASP.NET roadmap you linked to also says that "1.0.0 (Tools Preview 2)" is the latest version (it's in the Schedule table, though it's not mentioned in the Milestone Themes section).

Comment: Thanks, I did notice the difference between SDK/runtime and tools versions, but was then confused by the fact that there are installs available for "preview 3" and there is no Tools Preview 3 mentioned anywhere in the roadmap. So it seems like their package naming/numbering is very inconsistent.

Comment: @TobyJ Preview3 are packages created after the release of Preview 2. Presumably, there will be no release of Preview 3, that will be SDK 1.0.

Comment: Aaah ok that makes sense then... looking at just the build numbers then, it looks like they decided to switch from naming the package after just the Core (runtime) version to naming it after the SDK version, as "rc2" precedes "preview2", except for a couple outliers (e.g. rc2-23911) where the build numbers have extra digits. Maybe that's when they were testing their build scripts :)

Comment: And BTW that blog link has tons of good info in it, and confirms that `003121` is indeed the RTM build number (presumably on all platforms). Thanks for passing it along!